# How to unlock weapon slots in Pre-Sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I have a problem. I was level 20 when my friend joined my game, we beat it and now we're playing true vault hunter mode but my friend still only has 2 weapon slots. Will he unlock them in True Vault Hunter Mode? Or will he have to play the original story without me to unlock them?
(We're on xbox 360 so we can't hack or mod it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend needs to have the correct story missions completed, so have him start the game in single player, switch to Normal Mode (not True Vault Hunter Mode), and he should automatically get a prompt, asking him if he wants to skip missions he has already played. If he says yes, he should get his third and fourth weapon slots unlocked.

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: I never got the option to skip the missions...

Comment: Which mission specifically?